# Javafx TextField pseudoClassStateChanged method not working

Tags: java, javafx

I'm setting `PseudoClass` to `TextField` to highlight them when error occurs. 
The red border appears around `TextField` only when I click mouse inside it (to put text value), but I need to show border all time.

there is how I sets border:

```
element.pseudoClassStateChanged(PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("error"), true);
```

It worked just fine till last moment, maybe I switched accidentaly some option?

CSS file:

```
.text-field:error {
    -fx-focus-color: red ;
}

.table-view .column-header .label {
    -fx-font-weight: normal;
}

.list-cell:other-option {
    -fx-opacity: 0.5 ;
}

.titled-pane:pane-error  {
    -fx-border-color: red ;
}
```

Comment: There is no problem with the way you are changing the `psuedo class`. Can you add a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) explaining what you are trying to do.

Comment: In particular, can you show your CSS file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-fx-focus-color` is used only when focus is on the control. If you want a css that applies to the control, without focus, change the `-fx-background-color`.

From `modena.css`, `-fx-background-color` for `.text-input:focused` is

```
-fx-background-color: 
        -fx-focus-color,
        -fx-control-inner-background,
        -fx-faint-focus-color,
        linear-gradient(from 0px 0px to 0px 5px, derive(-fx-control-inner-background, -9%), -fx-control-inner-background);
```

You can just change the `-fx-focus-color` element in it to `red` :

```
-fx-background-color:
            red,
            -fx-control-inner-background,
            -fx-faint-focus-color,
            linear-gradient(from 0px 0px to 0px 5px, derive(-fx-control-inner-background, -9%), -fx-control-inner-background);
```

You can also change `-fx-control-inner-background` or `-fx-faint-focus-color`, as per your requirement.

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot. Maybe you can advice also how to highlight TitledPane border? May css section seems to be wrong

Comment: TitledPane seems to be alright and I can see a `red border` when your css is applied. Are you something else other than a red border around the TitledPane?